# How can I remap a key to itself followed by another key after a short delay?

Tags: autohotkey

How do I remap key so that when I press <kbd>2</kbd> or <kbd>3</kbd> it actually types `2q` or `3q` with a 50ms delay between the number and the letter?

This doesn't work:

```
2::
send 2
sleep, 30
send q
```

Comment: Is this specific to autohotkey or is it a batch file or something? Also, just wondering, what are you planning on doing with this? Sounds evil, but funny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remapping a key to send itself requires you to use the `$` modifier.

```
$2::
    SendInput, 2
    Sleep 30
    SendInput, q
Return
```